# What is the value of $\iiint_v\operatorname{div}(\operatorname{curl}G)\,dv$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

Let there be vector field $F$ and some surface $S$ which is without holes and closed.

We may want to calculate:
$$
\iint\operatorname{curl}F\cdot n\cdot ds
$$
where $n$ is the outer normal vector to the surface and $ds$ is the area element.

But $\operatorname{curl}F$ is a vector field in itself so let $G=\operatorname{curl}F$.

So according to Gauss theorem $\iint G\cdot n\cdot ds=\iiint_v\operatorname{div}G\,dv$ which is actually $\iiint \operatorname{div}(\operatorname{curl}F)\,dv$.

But we also know that $\operatorname{div}(\operatorname{curl}F)=0$.

So is $\iiint \operatorname{div}(\operatorname{curl}F)\,dv$ always $0$?

Comment: Since $\nabla \cdot \nabla \times \vec F=0$, then its integral is zero also.  Is that what you're asking??  And note that from Stokes' theorem, $\oint_S \nabla \times \vec F \cdot \hat n\,dS=0$

Comment: @MarkViola yes exactly

Comment: Note that from Stokes' theorem, $\oint_S \nabla \times \vec F \cdot \hat n\,dS=0$

Comment: @MarkViola the way we learnt Stoke's is that $\iint \operatorname{curl}F\cdot ndS=\oint F\cdot dr$ but it's not always zero

Comment: If the surface integral is closed, as I wrote, then $$\oint_S \nabla \times \vec F \cdot \hat n\,dS=0$$If the surface integral is not closed, then Stokes' Theorem is $$\int_S \nabla \times \vec F \cdot \hat n\,dS =\oint_{\partial S}\vec F \cdot d\vec \ell$$To see this, slice the closed surface integral into two open surfaces.   Now, apply Stokes' to each individual.  Note that the line integrals are equal but opposite in direction.

Comment: Does $S$ in your last equation represent one of those two open surfaces that you sliced from the closed surface?